# Access mySQL fields using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

After lot of temptatives and after reading lot of posts about I'm still unable to read mySQL fields using Jquery. My PHP code, which connects to a db and gets some data, outputs the following using `echo json_encode($html);`:

```
{"id":"1","title":"this_is_title","description":"this_is_description","url":"this_is_url"}
```

I then try to read the single fields but I keep getting "undefined". For example:

```
$.getJSON("get.php", function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(key, field){
         console.log(field.title);
    });
});
```

If I simply use `field` instead of `field.title` it works but I get all the fields (of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data contains only a single object, not an array of objects.

You are iterating over each property within this JSON object with `$.each`, so within that callback function `key` will be the property name and `field` will be the property *value*.

Change your console log call to this:

```
console.log(field);
```

and you can see the difference, the value will of the property will be logged.

You can access the properties of the JSON directly like so:

```
$.getJSON("get.php", function(result) {
     console.log(result.id);
     console.log(result.title);
     // etc
});
```

Comment: Ok, fine. But how I can access mySQL fields by field name? I saw codes that use the notation 'field.title'.

Comment: You don't need to use `$.each` to iterate over them. Remove that part and just  use `result.id`, `result.title` and so on

Answer (score 3):

If there is only a single object returned then you can easily access each field.
You already know the field names so use them.

```
$.getJSON("get.php", function(result) {
    console.log(result.id); 
    console.log(result.title);
    console.log(result.description);
    console.log(result.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use parseJSON and then try to access :

```
$.getJSON("get.php", function(result) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(obj, function(key, field){
     console.log(key); // here you will get index like id,title
     console.log(field); // here you will get value
    });
});
```

Comment: I get -> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data. Where could Json data be wrong?

Comment: Ok try    var obj = JSON.parse(result)

Comment: Sorry, same syntax error and now error also on var obj = JSON.parse(result). I would like to access data like this: 'field.title'. I see that 'field' and 'key' work but I looking for 'field.title'